# Opening external workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having little problem with my VBA Excel program. I'm trying to open external workbook with Application.Workbooks.Open() function. Filename of the external workbook comes from CommonDialog. When I select file with dialogbox and let the program load the workbook, for some reason Excel first loads some sort of copy of that file and then after it the file I wanted. This leads to problem where Excel starts whining about not enought resources. I've tried to give filename of the external workbook with simple string and when using it that way, Excel loads only the file I want it to load.

Here is the code:

```
CommonDialog1.Filter = "Excel-taulukot (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
Dim externalWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
'This one seems to load copy and the file'
Set externalWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(CommonDialog1.Filename, , True)
'This one works, but I need it to be little less hardcoded'
'Set externalWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open("<pathtofile>", , True)'
Set externalSheet = externalWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```

Comment: Although this suggestion will not have an effect on you current problem, shouldn't you be testing the Open Dialog for user-cancel?

Comment: You're right, I should do it, but it's not yet implemented to my code.

Comment: It would help if you posted all of your VBA code. I do not see where externalSheet is defined. Can you explain a little more about why you think some kind of copy is first being loaded?

Comment: The externalSheet is defined at the top of the module. There is all the code to give to you, because this logic happens only in this sub. When I run the code, I see text on the bottom-right corner saying it will load copy of my file and then it says it loads the file I want. When I pass the filename as string, it only says it loads the file I want.

Comment: Could you submit both documents here?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not possible because the file contains some classified information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. For some reason, disabling preview-window on dialog-screen stopped Excel to load copy of the file. Now it's working just how I wanted.

Comment: could you show the code you inserted to do that, as a reference for others with this issue in the future? Glad you figured it out

Comment: I did'nt add any code, I just disabled the preview from the dialog window. And by the way, thanks for everybody trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The xlsx format is a compressed format and it is likely that what you are seeing is a decompression to a temporary file for loading. Are you sure when you hardcode the filename it is not seeing it do the same thing when you step through in debug?

Comment: Yes, I'm positively sure about that. It's not doing the copy-thing with hard-coded version. Here is image describing the situtation: http://i43.tinypic.com/30j681k.jpg

Comment: Do you need the file to open read-only? It would seem the "Copy of..." might be related to that condition. Set the read-only part of the dialog to false and see if it behaves differently.

Comment: also what is invoking the form load the dialog is called from?

Comment: There seems to be no difference when I set read-only to false. Form is invoked in Workbook_Open sub.